# Swift 2.2 #selector for delegate/protocol compile error

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code:

```
protocol CustomControlDelegate: AnyObject {
    func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
}

class CustomControl: UIView {
    var delegate: CustomControlDelegate? {
         didSet {
             aButton.addTarget(delegate, action: "buttonTapped:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }
}
```

As of Swift 2.2, I get a compile error asking to use #selector. But I can't figure out how to correctly use #selector in this case.

The compiler gave this suggestion:

[image]

but when that is used, it gave another compile warning saying:

[image]

I tried this and i did not get a compile error, however, I doubt it's the right solution. I don't want to add `@objc` to my protocol:

```
@objc protocol CustomControlDelegate: AnyObject {
    func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
}

class CustomControl: UIView {
    var delegate: CustomControlDelegate? {
         didSet {
             aButton.addTarget(delegate, action: #selector(CustomControlDelegate.buttonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the compiler suggest the solution?

Comment: `#selector(CustomControlDelegate.buttonTapped(_:))` is the correct solution, at least that's the syntax the compiler usually suggests.

Comment: This is Xcode's suggestion: `Selector("buttonTapped:")` which does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the reason to avoid `@objc` here. The method must be `@objc` in order for the Objective-C runtime to invoke it. You can't put the `@objc` to the method declaration, so the only way to convey the intent is to make the protocol `@objc`.

```
@objc protocol CustomControlDelegate {
    func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
}
```

Although the protocol is `@objc`, the implementing class does not need to be `@objc` — just making the method `@objc` can make the compiler happy.

```
class MyControlDelegate: CustomControlDelegate {
// ^ no `@objc`, not deriving NSObject
    @objc func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    // ^ making just this method `@objc` is enough.

    }
}
```

then you could use `#selector(CustomControlDelegate.buttonTapped)` without errors or warnings.

Comment: The reason i want to avoid `objc` is since we're moving away from Objective-C, i would find it weird that Apple would force us to use objc, so I was thinking there must be a different (objc free) solution.

Comment: @VanDuTran UIKit is still written in ObjC, so you can't avoid the ObjC *runtime*. Besides, `#selector` is already an ObjC-specific feature. A few `@objc` is necessary to interact with the system frameworks.